# AWS s3 access PRIVATE bucket url from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubyzip

I'm new to RoR.

I'm creating a small app that uploads images and saves them in S3, the user cant attach all the images in a zip file and send it via email,to accomplish that im using **rubyzip** gem.

Locally it works fine (Im following the gem documentation)

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/

But in production for the "ZIP" action I need to give a source folder (in which is saved the image) and since all my images are saved in s3 bucket I give a path like the following:

```
folder = 'https://'bucket-name'.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

After research i fond similar cases, but none of them work for me, for example I tried
[How to retrieve attachment url with Rails Active Storage with S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791684/how-to-retrieve-attachment-url-with-rails-active-storage-with-s3) and it give me "No such file or directory"

```
2018-11-15T00:44:27.082416+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-11-15T00:44:27.082337 #4]  INFO -- : [db52fa26-32c2-4f7e-a766-7d39fd3ef062] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1532ms (ActiveRecord: 21.4ms)
2018-11-15T00:44:27.082915+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-11-15T00:44:27.082844 #4] FATAL -- : [db52fa26-32c2-4f7e-a766-7d39fd3ef062]
2018-11-15T00:44:27.082988+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-11-15T00:44:27.082916 #4] FATAL -- : [db52fa26-32c2-4f7e-a766-7d39fd3ef062] Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com):
2018-11-15T00:44:27.083054+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-11-15T00:44:27.082985 #4] FATAL -- : [db52fa26-32c2-4f7e-a766-7d39fd3ef062]
```

My bucket is private so, make sense that it doesn't let me access it until I provide correct credentials, and here is the part where I dont have idea how to send the signature in the url to authenticate.
I have tried something like the following but it keeps giving me weird simbols

```
kDate = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + secret_access_key, dateStamp)
    kRegion = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, regionName)
    kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, serviceName)
    signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")


    puts("#{s3_base_url}?AWSAccessKeyId=#{access_key_id}
            &Expires=#{expiration_date}
            &Signature=#{signature}")
```

this is the result when i print the signature

```
https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com?AWSAccessKeyId=my-access-key
            &Expires=1542416076
            &Signature=Q�����>�9`o���r}�9��`�m��g��
```

Ps. Im also have created a IAM user with admin privileges

Thanks, Im using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.0
Im super new with dealing with AMAZON so excuse if my question is to obvious

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about constructing a signed URL manually; I've never tried it. However, the AWS gem has a `presigned_url` method for S3 objects that will construct them for you. You can then use that URL to access the object in the private bucket.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#presigned_url-instance_method

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new bucket_name
object = bucket.object object_key
object.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: expiry)
```