# Can't retrieve file from S3 with Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am trying to upload a photo to S3 using Rails Active Storage.

I can attach a photo:

`user.photo.attach(io: File.open('spec/images/filename.png'), filename: 'filename.png')`

I can save the user and I can get the photo service url and see it in the browser, and in my bucket:

`user.photo.service_url`

However, if I restart my console and try to get the service url, I receive the following error:

`Module::DelegationError (service_url delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil)`

Here are my bucket settings:

storage.yml:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket) %>
```

application.rb:

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

user.rb:

`has_one_attached :photo`

I am also having trouble using `public: true` in the storage.yml file.

I receive the following error if I try to set the config:

```
ArgumentError (Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`:)
invalid configuration option `:public'
```

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket) %>
  public: true
```

Comment: Did you set also ```config.active_storage.service = :amazon``` in ```config/environments/development.rb``` and ```config/environments/production.rb``` files

Comment: Consider using `Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:aws).fetch(:access_key_id)` instead of dig which will raise an error if its not present on startup instead of when its used which is very helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to upload my files to AWS S3, and have them publically available.

I ran into this issue as well and found the following:

```rb
ArgumentError (Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`:)
invalid configuration option `:public'
```

comes from [this file in the `aws-sdk-ruby` gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb#L167). As per the error message, the aws-sdk-ruby gem does not support the `public: true` option.

I used the following work-around (special thanks to [this article](https://www.mmbyte.com/article/40111.html)):

1. I updated my storage.yml to:

```yaml
public_amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: some_key
  secret_access_key: some_secret
  bucket: some-bucket-name
  region: some-region
  upload:
    acl: "public-read"
```

The above sets the uploaded file permissions to be public.

2. Retrieve the public URL like this:

```rb
user.photo.attach(params[:file])
url = user.photo.service.send(:object_for, user.photo.key).public_url
```

Comment: as mentioned in a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906011/7573223) it is bad practice to call `send` in this case.  `user.photo.service_url.sub(/\?.*/, '')` yields the same result without having to call the service as mentioned in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822787/7573223)