# Rails Active Storage Local attachemnt failing with cryptic errror: uninitialized constant Analyzable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

ruby '2.7.1'  / rails 6.0.3.2

I can't get local active storage attachements to work. Here is my setup:

I have run:

```
$ rails active_storage:install
$ rake db:migrate
```

Model schema

```
  create_table "amazon_uploads" do |t|
    t.string "status"
    t.string "order_csv"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

model:

```
class AmazonUpload < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :amazon_upload_recipients

  has_one_attached :order_csv
end
```

my storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

my development.rb contains:

```
  config.active_storage.service = :local
```

And then in my code I do:

```rb
    file = File.open(updated_file_path)
    @amazon_upload.order_csv.attach(io: file, filename: "hello", content_type: "application/CSV")
```

the last line fails with

```
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000564c2f7e8638>::Analyzable
```

The only other reference I can see to this error the person claims they had a type but I don't think that's the issue here

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ChrisHough no as far as I can tell this is literally broken in core which is nuts to me. Other people have open issues in the rails core git repo though.

Answer (score 2):

it's zeitwerk bug
you can just upgrade your rails version to 6.1.x and everything should work fine

if you don't want to upgrade - switch to the classic load mode by adding in application.rb

```
config.autoloader = :classic
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just add

```
include ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable
```